# Trying to bind one of the property of class to a textbox via autocomplete using jQuery and Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Issue: Trying to bind one of the property of class to a textbox via autocomplete.

I have a Web API method that returns a List of Employees as output. Employee is a class that contains name, age, address, dateofbirth etc as properties.

When someone types few characters in a name text box, I want to autocomplete/autosuggest it.

For ex:

Name: Maxwell

If someone types "Ma", I want to auto suggest names

Matt
Matthew
Maxwell

and allow the user to select one.

Code I used is:

`GetNameInformation` - Returns list of employees.

```
$("#autocomplete-1")
            .autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/GetNameInformation?user=ma',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(json) {
                            return {
                                Name: json.Name

                            }
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            // error handling
                        }
                    }); // ajax
                } // source
            });
```

I am also referencing these 2 on my html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

My html page has

```
<label for="autocomplete-1">Name: </label>
<input id="autocomplete-1">
```

Also, i don't see the data on the popup:

[image]

Comment: What's the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: Nothing happens, the name doesn't get auto suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Changed your code to this:

```js
$( "#autocomplete-1" ).autocomplete({
      source: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1bf4z5",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        alert( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<label for="autocomplete-1">Name: </label>
<input id="autocomplete-1">
```

Note the url sent for ajax. The response from that URL should be an array of json objects like this:

```
[{"id":"Branta canadensis","label":"Greater Canada Goose","value":"Greater Canada Goose"},{"id":"Branta hutchinsii","label":"Lesser Canada Goose","value":"Lesser Canada Goose"}]
```

PS. Since the url is cross domain, it won't work. I'm pasting the url here so that you know what request goes as ajax: `https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=canad`
Where `canad` is the text typed in the autocomplete.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work, when i type "canad", it threw "no results found".

Comment: That's what I said, 'Since the url is cross domain, it won't work.' But the code is as it should be for autocomplete. Do the changes as I wrote and your code will work :)

Comment: Nevermind, updated the url to a dummy one. Its working now. Please note I've hardcoded it to search only for `canad`

Comment: Thanks.

I am not able to select rows, also not able to see data, the web api returns data, when i type few characters, the textbox loads downward popup with list of data(i can only see rows, not actual data), any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I used this pattern & it worked.
> ```

```
 $("#autocomplete-1")
                .autocomplete({
                    source: "MyMethodURL",
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $("#autocomplete-1").val(ui.item.Name);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                    var inner_html = '<table><tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td></tr></table>';
                    return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append(inner_html)
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };
        })(jQuery);
```